How would a magic system allowing arbitrary organ transplants work?
Imagine a society with an otherwise Medieval level of technology. But this is a fantasy world, having magic. Specifically this magic enables advanced surgical procedures be done using otherwise medieval technology. The more mundane aspects of this magic means treatment of wounds and surgeries are much more successful. The more fantastical aspects of this magic means that any arbitrary organ transplants can be done successfully. This magic also takes care of all and any immune system rejection.
It would be possible to transplant organs from any one human body to another human body without any problems, provided that all the blood vessels and nerves be correctly sewn together. For example, transplanting limbs, eyes, and internal organs. However the limbs and organs need not necessarily be human! It is possible to transplant limbs and organs from freshly killed animals onto humans. For example if some warrior wants to have a bear claw for an arm. This has lead into an entire practice of "biological transhumanism", augmentation of the human body by adding onto it animal body parts.
The cultural background of this "Medieval society" is that they are like Southwestern US Natives such as the inhabitants of Mesa Verda, but dialed up to 10, such that they are like Ancient Egypt in level of development. It is within such a fantasy society that I want this magic system to be present.
My question is, how could such a magical system work? How would such a society with an otherwise "Medieval" level of development be able to weild such a magic system effectively?

"My question is, how could such a magical system work?" wasn't all the text before this sentence the explanation of how it worked?

How does it work? Magic...

There is very, very limited ability for nerves to be "correctly sewn together" with today's technology and definitely insufficient technology in medieval times to sew blood vessels together - given that these are the essential actions that must be completed non-magically, it seems to render the "magic" useless.  However, I second @VLAZ that you seem to have said what the magic does, so it's unclear what you are asking.  (Please do not ask how to make the magic "realistic"!)

The answer, too trivial for more than a comment, is: Very well, apparently.

"How would such a society with an otherwise "Medieval" level of development be able to weild such a magic system effectively?" would seem to be down to their training or inherent talent.  But you've 2 questions here, we have a 1 question rule. Could you pick one and tell us what sort of answer you're looking for.

I think the thing that a lot of worldbuilders misunderstand about magic is that it's exactly that: magic. Science explains where you start, where you end up, and the path to get there by using physics/chemistry/etc to explain the changes that happen along the way to bring an initial state to a final state. Magic tells you where you start and where you end up, but the intervening space between those two states is just handwaved as magic. This is the difference between a neurosurgeon's report on a surgery and waving a hand over a head and magically repairing a tumor.

(contd) So if you want magic, don't explain it - it's magic. If you try and explain it, it becomes science, and if you're trying to create a realistic science, you have a lot of new problems.

There is no plausible way for such transplants to work on their own.
But since you are leaning towards "Magical transhumanism angle" why not pick a magical biological agent to go with it?
Suppose there is this kind of magical cave slime-mold, that bonds symbiotically with just about any animal, substituting for blood vessels, nerves etc. On its own it tends to be rather inert and occasionally "benevolently infect" cave organisms.
But intentionally suing it as "glue" to stick an organ into another being allows the Symbiote Mold to truly take hold and work its magic. The Mold is a rare and guarder resource, as it can only reproduce in very specific circumstances.
There could be even rumors of a Parasite Mold, an evil version of the Symbiote Mold, that instead of patching together injured beings, forcefully melds and fleshcrafts captured prey into nightmarish amalgamations of flailing limbs and organs that beg to be put out of their misery as they chase you...

The conflict here is we typically see magic as an element removed from the current level of technology. However, mage colleges would have to be fairly "advanced" in order to study and control their magic.
I bring this up, because your transplants are possible. However the success of the procedures would require some scientific rigor with trial and error. We have used pig heart valves, some of our insulin supply is grown in pig pancreas(s), and I'm pretty sure I've see an article about grafting an ear to a mouse.
The key problem is compatibility between systems. Suppose you use a bear arm. Are the nerve endings, blood vessels, muscles tissue compatible with the host? Will the immune system reject the new tissue? Can the hosts blood cells even supply oxygen and energy to the new arm? All of these answers could ve found out through trial and error as well as many many victims -erm patients.
Ultimately, magic is magic so if you create a permanent magical interface between the new part to translate the signals and energy requirements, you can graft anything to anything.
